How can I repair this open cavity in our bump-out?
In our rear addition, there are two 2'x6' bump outs with windows, which provide a little more space in the rear of the house.  The bump outs are cantilevered beyond the foundation and I believe the structure under the bump outs is letting in cold air into the house (basement & main floor).
The bump outs have wooden frame at the base with a plastic bottom covering, and it's falling apart.  I think structure was created to support an HVAC vent in that space.  I'm pretty sure that's why the floor inside is absolutely freezing in the winter.
Can this be fixed from outside the house?





You should separate this into three problems, and probably three different questions with the best photos you can provide for each one.

Why is the cladding under your bumpout disintegrating?  Looks like wrong materials and wrong fasteners but I can't tell from the one photo.
How to insulate around the duct
How to insulate the bottom of the bumpout generally.

You should make THIS question, just question 3 -- and then the answer is, it's a very basic requirement and there are lots of systems and approaches that really amount to "just insulate it"!   Here's one, that's just randomly the first thing that came up in a search.
Me, I'd use the largest solid foam insulation blocks I could fit between the joists because I think they're easier to work with.  And spray foam around the ducts for the same reason.   I'd also put a thin  solid veneer of some kind, maybe the thinnest composite board I could find, over top the whole thing but Definitely with the stuff in the video because otherwise animals will nest inside it!
The stapled chicken wire may keep larger vermin out but makes it harder to clean and maintain under there.  I'd use something more solid or a purpose made porch skirt material, held in place with thumb screws for easy annual removal.

Thanks for the feedback.  I took the bottom covering off and realized this structure was a cantilever.  To my dismay, the builder did not install blocking in the joist bays.  I could look straight through to the other side of my house.  That explains the cold floors.
I remedied by removing and painting the bottom panel, to give it some extra protection from the elements.  I put blocking in each joist bay and spray foamed.  This was incredibly difficult, because I was under the deck with about 18" of clearance for my body.  It took me about about 6 hours just to block off the 10 bays total, I wouldn't wish this work on anyone.
Insulated each joist bay under the flooring with R30-ish batts.  Insulated the inside of the cover with expanded polystyrene board insulation, probably R3-ish.
Finally, I used screws with washers to fasten the board to the underside of the cantilever and got a nice tight seal, filled in with spray foam.
The floors are warmer in the kitchen and the basement ceiling is no longer freezing.
Success.
